# Error memory allocation on refresh design

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, allocation, designer

During a refresh design of a database Notes-Domino I have received the following error

```
Design Refresh Failed, Memory allocation request exceeded 65,000 bytes
```

I have tried to move all Xpages and all Custom Controls into another database, and then I switched to "Show Eclipse Views - Package Explorer." I have also deleted residual files under Custom Control Folder, and then I have pasted all Custom Controls and all XPages. I have cleaned and I have rebuilded the project, but the problem persists.

Server release 9.0.1 FP3
My Designer release 9.0.1

Comment: Try this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21613473

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists